# How can I access JSON identifiers from Twig?

Tags: json, twig

These are my JSON data:

```
[  
{  
  "name":"unit 1",
  "lessons":{  
     "1":{  
        "name":"lesson 1",
        "content":"......."
        },
     "2":{
        "name" "lesson 2",
        "content":"......."
        }
}
]
```

I can access these data using the following Twig code:

```
{% for unit in units %}
  {{ unit.name }}
  {% for lesson in unit.lessons %}
    {{ lesson.name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to access the lesson number, to make a hyperlink to the content. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Iterating over Keys and values](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values) as example:

```
{% for key, lesson in unit.lessons %}
    {{ key}}
    {{ lesson.name }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Hope this help